# Reading material on hosting MSHTML.DLL directly (not WebBrowser)?

Tags: winapi, com, mshtml, shdocvw, trident

Can anyone suggest good reading material on hosting **MSHTML.DLL/Trident** directly (not **SHDOCVW.DLL/WebBrowser**)? I want to use it for GUI elements, sometimes major ones, in C++. I need HTML rendering, JavaScript with extra host-provided DOM methods and properties, events.

My impression is that WebBrowser just adds an extra layer providing nothing I need, and more than that, things I'll have to work to disable: cross-page navigation, history, UI, context menus, registry dependencies, generic Active Document hosting, downloading, etc.

All the articles I find talk about the WebBrowser control, even if calling it MSHTML in many cases. The Microsoft documentation makes it difficult to understand what's MSHTML and what's WebBrowser; for example, ["Other MSHTML Interfaces"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lists IWebBrowser2, which is not part of MSHTML.DLL, among other things.

Comment: Mshtml only provides the HTML parser and the DOM.  You still need to get it to the screen to actually *see* the web page.  Which is what the "useless" shdocvw does.  Implementing it yourself is very unpractical.  You can't ask for off-site resources here.

Comment: Did you read [Hosting and Reuse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752038(v=vs.85).aspx), [Reusing MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508516(v=vs.85).aspx) and so on?

Comment: @HansPassant, according to the [MS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752038(v=vs.85).aspx), using WebBrowser is better because it provides "in-place navigation, history ... it encapsulates the expanded capabilities of the browser", while using MSHTML "you gain the use of an HTML and CSS parser and renderer, but you cannot take advantage of the browser's other capabilities".

Comment: @CodeCaster, of course.

Comment: So, what is your question? You can let MSHTML talk to an Active Document you host, so it renders to and interacts with an interface element under your control.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I'm unclear about the whole procedure.

Comment: @crackers, for learning more about MSHTML hosting, check this out: http://www.itwriting.com/htmleditor/index.php

Comment: @Noseratio, thanks, I'll have a look. Hopefully C# doesn't hide too much of the COM plumbing.

Answer (score 2):

MSHTML is an Active Document server. WebBrowser and Internet Explorer are Active Document hosts. If you want to host MSHTML directly, you get to implement all your own Active Document hosting interfaces, e.g. `IOleDocumentSite` or `IOleInPlaceFrame` (this is on top of regular OLE hosting interfaces, that might be provided by your framework of choice).

In addition, MSHTML requires its host to implement `ITargetContainer` and `ITargetFrame`. These are poorly documented.

Besides, as you probably already know, MSHTML doesn't support navigation. You have to download (or otherwise obtain) HTML content and feed it to the object.

For these reasons, it is difficult to host MSHTML directly, except in certain limited scenarios (e.g. as a UI-less HTML parser, see [WalkAll](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=944) sample). This is why there is so little information and so few samples on the topic. Most of the time, it's not worth the trouble. Just host a WebBrowser control, navigate it to `about:blank`, grab the MSHTML instance it hosts with `IWebBrowser2::get_Document`, and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems, in fact, that MSHTML/Trident does implement some things I thought WebBrowser did, like context menus. I'll just have to play with it.